# initialize numpy multidimensional empty array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

How can I define multidimensional array in numpy such that:

1. I can initialize the array with a specific shape
2. is initialized as empty
3. I can access a specific block of the array by array[a:b,c:d,...]

I would like to have something like:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array(value = None, shape = (n1,n2,n3,...))
```

I could do:

```
X = np.empty(shape = (n1,n2,n3,...))
```

But the array is filled with zeros, so checks like `.size` return a non-zero value.

I need to check if some blocks are empty when accessing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `empty`?  What `dtype` do you want - integer, float, ?  Why do you want a fill value of `None`?  `.size` depends on the shape of the block, not on its contents.

Comment: `X.size` will be 0 only if one of `n1,n2,...` is 0.

Comment: I'll try to explain my issue here a little better. I would like to have an array initialized to empty values (so I think `None`), such that later I can check if some blocks of this array are still empty for not. Then I need to put this is empty / non-empty statement in an if condition. To be more specific, the array will contain images (more than 3 channels though, as if stacked)
About `X.size`, that was something I read in an other thread, not really useful in my case.

Comment: Do you realize a object array contains pointers, like a list?  Access is list like, but slower.

Comment: shouldn't access to an array be faster than a list? Yes, I understand that any object has a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `None` entries, the dtype must be `object`.

Try

```
X = np.full(shape = (n1,n2,n3,...), fill_value = None,)
```

Comment: ok, but then how can I check if a block is empty in this case?

Comment: I think I might got it with `X[n1,:,:,n4:n5].all() == None`

Comment: `np.empty((n1,n2,n3,...), object)` makes an array filled with `None`.  Normally `np.empty` makes a array that contains what ever bytes were already present in the data buffer.  But with `object` those bytes are interpreted as pointers - and you don't want to be pointing random spots in memory.  The `None` object is the safe alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a numpy array with specific shape with the following steps
   [Numpy array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVTNX.png)

```
import numpy
X = numpy.zeros(shape=(3,2))
X[1]
```

Comment: I don't want it to be filled with zeros though